# Powerpoint Viewer Auto Accept Licence

Tags: installation, powerpoint

I have an installer that puts Powerpoint 2007 viewer onto the PC. It then opens a powerpoint file.  The problem is the PPT viewer needs to have a user accept the licence agreement before the PPT file will display.
Is there are registry setting for this licence agreement so that the user does not have to accept it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key responsible for this is

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\PowerPoint Viewer\12.0]
"EULAAccepted"=dword:00000001
```